# How give each button a different image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image

I have a application where you have 3 buttons and if you press a button the button image of the three buttons change but button 2 and button 3 may not have the same picture as button 1 and button 3 may not have the same picture as button 2

I have tried this but it didn't work

```
       NSInteger imageIndex1 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
       NSInteger imageIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
       NSInteger imageIndex3 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);

    if (imageIndex1 == imageIndex2 ) {
        imageIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
    }

    else if (imageIndex1 == imageIndex3  ) {
        imageIndex3 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
    }

        else if (imageIndex2 == imageIndex3  ) {
            imageIndex3 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);

    }



    else
       [self.picture1 setImage:images[imageIndex1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.picture2 setImage:images[imageIndex2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.picture3 setImage:images[imageIndex3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      imageIndex1 = imageIndex2;
      imageIndex1 = imageIndex3;
      imageIndex2 = imageIndex3;
```

Comment: Instead of `images[imageIndex2]` and `images[imageIndex3]` use `images[imageIndex1]`

Answer (score 0):

Here you set the `self.picture1` image in else part so if first any condition true then `self.picture1` image will not set so this problem you face also add the code for setImage for every button out of `else` part , bellow code

```
       [self.picture1 setImage:images[imageIndex1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.picture2 setImage:images[imageIndex2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.picture3 setImage:images[imageIndex3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 if (imageIndex2 == imageIndex1 ) {
            imageIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
    }

    if (imageIndex3 == imageIndex1 ) {
            imageIndex3 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
          }


[self.picture1 setImage:images[imageIndex1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.picture2 setImage:images[imageIndex2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.picture3 setImage:images[imageIndex3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       imageIndex1 = imageIndex2;
       imageInde

x1 = imageIndex3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSInteger imageIndex1 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
NSInteger imageIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
NSInteger imageIndex3 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);

while (imageIndex2 == imageIndex1 ) {
    imageIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
}

while (imageIndex3 == imageIndex1 ) {
    imageIndex3 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
}


[self.picture1 setImage:images[imageIndex1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.picture2 setImage:images[imageIndex2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.picture3 setImage:images[imageIndex3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i have the solution found.
This is the code now:

```
    Boolean p1 =true;
    Boolean p2 = true;
    Boolean p3 = true;


       NSInteger imageIndex1 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
       NSInteger imageIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);
       NSInteger imageIndex3 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);

    if (imageIndex1 == imageIndex2 ) {
        p1 = false;
        imageIndex2 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);

    }

    if(imageIndex1 == imageIndex3  ) {
        p2 = false;
        imageIndex1 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);

    }

       if (imageIndex2 == imageIndex3  ) {
           p3 = false;
            imageIndex3 = arc4random_uniform(images.count);


    }



    if(p1 == true && p2 == true && p3 == true) {
       [self.picture1 setImage:images[imageIndex1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.picture2 setImage:images[imageIndex2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.picture3 setImage:images[imageIndex3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the other copy of this was closed as duplicate.  Here's the answer from that one:  The goal of the question is to change images on buttons at random.  But the problem is that picking a random index into an array of images sometimes generates the current index (it's random, so this happens with 1/array.count probability).  Here's an approach that excludes a given index...

```
- (NSUInteger)randomUnsignedLessThan:(NSInteger)max excluding:(NSUInteger)exclude {

    NSInteger firstTry = -1;
    while (firstTry == exclude) firstTry = arc4random() % max;
    return firstTry;
}
```

Note that this approach will always call arc4random once, and require 1+N calls with a probability of 1/max^N, so for low ranges, and high performance requirements, you might consider a different algorithm to exclude the one index.